# Can i send an object to isolated scope '@' property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which accepts object as a parameter (attribute). I am getting the data in my link function as string. Is there any way to receive the data as object keeping `@` in the attribute and without using eval or `JSON.parse()` in link.

**Directive code:**

```
module.directive('example', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            object: '@'
        }
        link: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.object);
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<example object="{{sampleObject}}"></example>
```

**Controller code:**

```
module.controller('exampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sampleObject = {
        name: 'name',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Result of "@" binding is always a string, since this way you bind the value of DOM attribute. See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

If you are searching a way to avoid two-way data binding, use "&" expression.